# Selecting all the rows between Two specific Strings in DataFrame Column using Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a DataFrame and in it, there is a Column by the name of Events. 
So what I want to do is collect all the rows between Events value from String "Event Start" to "Event End". i.e. all the rows when "Event Start" came till "Event End" arrives in the column. This "Event Start" to "Event End" will be done multiple times in the column and all the other rows that arrive between "Event End" to "Event Start" are to be dropped.

Used `.filter` but it only gives the rows of "Event Start" and "Event End" but not the rows in between

```
val df1 = selectedDf.filter(($"Event" === "Event Start"))

val df2 = selectedDf.filter(($"Event" === "Event End"))
```

Data is somewhat like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGtaS.png)

Comment: can you add small sample of your data and what you try to achive ?

Comment: @vaquarkhan added in the question. as you can see the column Event

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
val data = spark.read.csv("data/sort.csv").toDF("val")
data.show()

+---+
|val|
+---+
|AAA|
|ABC|
|ABD|
|ABF|
|DEF|
|DEZ|
|ZZZ|
+---+

data.filter('val >= "ABC" && 'val <= "DEF").show()
+---+
|val|
+---+
|ABC|
|ABD|
|ABF|
|DEF|
+---+
```

Comment: Sorry for being vague in the question, my Strings are "Event Starts" and "Event End" so > and < won't work.  Can you suggest me something else please

Answer (score 0):

Hope following example help:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("MS 1","X"), ("MS 2", "Y"), ("MS 3", "X"), ("MS 4", "E"), ("MS 3", "E"))).toDF("ms", "event")

df.show

val fileter1DF = df.filter(col("event") === "X")

val filter2DF = df.filter(col("event") === "E")

val result = fileter1DF.as("x").join(filter2DF.as("e"), List("ms"), "left_outer").where(col("e.event").isNull).select(col("x.ms"))

result.show
```

Results :

```
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.4.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.12 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_131)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("MS 1","X"), ("MS 2", "Y"), ("MS 3", "X"), ("MS4 2", "E"), ("MS 3", "E"))).toDF("ms", "event")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [ms: string, event: string]

scala> df.show
+-----+-----+
|   ms|event|
+-----+-----+
| MS 1|    X|
| MS 2|    Y|
| MS 3|    X|
| MS 4|    E|
| MS 3|    E|
+-----+-----+


scala> val fileter1DF = df.filter(col("event") === "X")
fileter1DF: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [ms: string, event: string]

scala> val filter2DF = df.filter(col("event") === "E")
filter2DF: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [ms: string, event: string]

scala> val result = fileter1DF.as("x").join(filter2DF.as("e"), List("ms"), "left_outer").where(col("e.event").isNull).select(col("x.ms"))
result: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [ms: string]

scala> result.show
+----+
|  ms|
+----+
|MS 1|
+----+


scala>
```

Comment: Sir vaquar khan maybe I wasn't clear in my question. I want all the rows from evey X till every E if you look at your example. Maybe you can help me with that.
e.g:

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("MS 1","X"), ("MS 2", "E"), ("MS 3", "Y"), ("MS 4", "X"), ("MS 5", "E"))).toDF("ms", "event")

I want MS1, MS2, MS4 and MS5 after every step